# jQuery - Do only once

Tags: jquery

I want to check if an element has the class .active, if it does add: margin-top: 4px;

However I only want this to occur **once**, when the page loads, once the class has been detected I don't want to detect it again and add the CSS style.

This class is applied when certain elements are hovered over.

Is this possible in jQuery?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Check out the [one](http://api.jquery.com/one/) event. Documented example:

```
$('#foo').one('click', function() {
  alert('This will be displayed only once.');
});
```

Comment: I don't think "one" will solve danits problem. Can one be bound to document ready?

Comment: @Hunter - The op said 'This is class is applied when certain elements are hovered over.' which led me to believe that he wants a mouseover event to fire just once on certain elements. I could be wrong, of course, in which case your answer is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 3):

This will fire once on page load

```
$(function(){ 
    if ($("#elementid").hasClass("active"))
    {
        $("#elementid").css("margin-top", "4px");
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't think "one" is necessary in this case. Using this solution will work --- document.ready fires only once.

Answer (score 2):

The way I usually do this is:

```
(function($) {

  // my custom function to process elements
  function myProcessFunction(context) {

    // get context    
    context = context || document;

    // select elements within the context, filter out already processed ones
    // loop through remained (unprocessed) elements
    // '.my-class' - selector for the elements I want to process
    $('.my-class:not(.my-class-processed)', context).each( function(i.e){

      // mark the element as processed
      $(e).addClass('my-class-processed');

      // add process code here 

    });
  }

  // run myProcessFunction on document.ready 
  $(document).ready( function(){
    myProcessFunction();
  });

})(jQuery);
```

This way I have:

- reusable function
- processed elements are marked and won't be processed next time the function is called
- elements are processed within the context only, if specified (for instance, HTML code returned via an AJAX request)

Hope this helps )