# How can I zoom only for once?

Tags: jquery

I'm using ajax to show the html and for that html I'm using zoom css with jquery but when I first view the page it zooms to what I use for zoom value but after again going back to that page from another page it again zooms from that zoomed state.

```
$(selector).css('zoom','.8');
```

So, how can I zoom only for once?

---

Suppose firstly html content was at zoom: 1; original state.

Next when I see the page it zooms to .8 as I set.

Again if I'm back to the page it zooms again by .8 means it was first .8 and now it's .8*.8 = .64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this...

```
var zoom_val = 0.8;
var local_zoom;
$("#btn1").on("mouseover",function(){   
   localStorage.setItem('zoom', zoom_val);
   local_zoom = localStorage.getItem('zoom');
   $("#btn1").css('zoom',local_zoom);
});
```

Comment: I tried flag way too, but still zooming time and again.

Comment: I think the variable isn't stored when I back again?

Comment: @NavinRauniyar you can use local storage for this. Now try the above code. If not working, please dont give downvote, just tell me I'll answer you.

Comment: ok. I'll try.... thanks, don't mind please, just down vote is to indicate not working...but I didn't downvote first..

Comment: its ok.  just tell me, i'll answer you.

Comment: Yep, it's working. thanks. Do you have another idea.

Comment: Not now. This what I know.

Comment: I just found [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2539269/jquery-do-only-once) but didn't know how to use this (the last answer). I think it's good way, please try to explain how to use if you understand.

Comment: I didn't say about one but Eugene Kubovsky answer.